# Poblems with minipages in LyX in main pdf file

Tags: lyx, pdf, minipage, document-configuration

I am writing my thesis in  LyX. It is in the report class and have two chapters as child documents. Both chapters have objects on mini pages.

Both chapters produce fine pdf independently. But in the master pdf the second chapter the objects on the minipages are disturbed, while in the first chapter everything is OK.

Particularly:
    on the one minipage I have 'title', 'author' and 'abstract', with 'title' and 'author' are displayed as just text;
    on the other minipage the right bar of the left column plot boxes is gone.
[image]
(The left side is master pdf; the right side is chapter pdf)

I have looked in source files of the both files and in the document settings. Nothing is different.
I am really in trouble.

Comment: In order to help you better, we need to be able to see what you're seeing, or at least see the code. Provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that we can use to replicate your problem...

Comment: How are the pictures on the other page not complete (what do you mean)? It's hard to see any difference in your posted picture

Comment: Two titles ans two author in the same document? There are exceptions in another classes, but usually  that is not a good idea.

Comment: I see. Is there any way to trick the specifications? I want the thesis to look as a collection of articles?

Comment: You can use a different document class. For example book. It has chapters. I believe that is the most common approach for dissertations. There are several .lyx files if you google that people have used for dissertations.

Comment: Also, be aware that when you include a .lyx file in a master .lyx file, the preamble from the included .lyx file is ignored. This can cause surprises to some users.